# Emr bootstrap script file location

Tags: amazon-emr

Hi I have a bash script that uploads a file to dnsmasq and starts the dnsmasq service. However while bootstrapping its failing with the below error. 
Please let me know on which folder is readable in EMR so that i can save my scripts in that folder and run it there.

I tried to place it inside /ec2-user/ and also in /root/ both cases i am getting the same error

Error:

```
warning: Skipping file /root/. File/Directory is not readable.
cp: cannot stat ‘/root/bootstrap-actions/10-consul’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/root/bootstrap-actions/’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘30-hq’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/root/bootstrap-actions/20-aws’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/root/bootstrap-actions/40-mesos-dns-us-east-1’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/root/bootstrap-actions/dnsmasq.conf’: No such file or directory
~
```

Comment: Put the file in S3 and use that path.

Answer (score 2):

Place the bootstrap script in a s3 bucket of the same region as EMR and load the script from S3 in bootstrap action. This will work.